# Speeding up process time while archiving files

Tags: c#, performance, file, archive

I'm new to `C#` and have created a basic file archiver. It works, and it does what it's suppose to do, but I think it's pretty slow. I added a simple `benchmark` to it in order to test the speed and ran it five times.

1. 50.7120707 seconds
2. 46.5686564 seconds
3. 50.2020197 seconds
4. 44.8384834 seconds
5. 44.5264522 seconds

So the average time for this process to run is 47.369536648 seconds. I understand that depending on the size of the files it's archiving and depending on how many files plays a big roll, so here's an image of the file sizes that I'm using as my test:

[image]

[image]

So the files really aren't to big, so I'm not sure if this is a good process time or not, it seems a little slow to me and I was wondering if there's anyway I can speed this up?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ArchiveCreator
{
    class Archive
    {

        //These static strings are used for 
        //information handling they will be
        //color coordinated so you can see
        //what kind of information is being 
        //passed to you
        static string Success(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        static string Warn(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        static string Say(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        static string FatalErr(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        static string MinorErr(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }

        //Main method
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //These variables are used to create a
            //random string that will be used as the
            //zip files name
            var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
            var randFileName = new char[4];
            var random = new Random();

            //Create the zip file name
            for (int i = 0; i < randFileName.Length; i++)
            {
                randFileName[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }
            string finalString = new String(randFileName);

            Say("Starting file extraction..");

            string day = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy ");
            string userName = Environment.UserName;
            string startDir = $"c:/users/{userName}/test_folder";
            string zipDir = $"c:/users/{userName}/archive/{day}{finalString}.zip";
            string dirName = $"c:/users/{userName}/archive";

            //Check if the directory exists
            Say("Attempting to create archive directory..");
            if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
            {
                MinorErr("Directory already exists, resuming extraction process");
            }
            else
            {
                //Create it if it doesn't
                Warn($"Creating archive directory here: {dirName}");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
                Say("Directory created, resuming process..");
            }

            try
            {
                //Attempt to extract to zip file
                Say($"Attempting to extract files into: {zipDir}");
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startDir, zipDir);
                Success($"Extracted files successfully to: {zipDir}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Catch any error that occurs during
                //the archiving stage and log the error
                //to a text file for further analysis
                var programPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                FatalErr($"Something went wrong and the program cannot continue, exiting process with error code {e}..");
                FatalErr("Writing error to file for further analysis.");
                File.WriteAllText($"{programPath}/log/errorlog.txt", e.ToString());
            }

            Say("Press enter to exit..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Asked on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129128/speeding-up-process-time-while-archiving-files)

Comment: You might have better luck posting this here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How long does WinZIP/WinRAR/7ZIP take to archive these files?

Comment: @TimFreese I thought about that, but I was a little weary because CodeReview says you cannot ask to add thing s to the program

Comment: @Blorgbeard I have no idea, I haven't even attempted them.

Comment: Well maybe you should..? If they take about the same time, there's probably no major optimizations for you to do.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Just attempted, it takes a lot longer, to long to even let it finish

Comment: @BlorgbeardUsing the basic right click compression it takes well over a minute for the system to send these to a zip file.

Comment: Well, sounds like your code is pretty fast then! In any case, your code is just a wrapper for [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721.aspx), so there's not any "optimization" you can do, apart from passing different arguments to it. You could try a different CompressionLevel - you may get faster results by using lower compression.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129128/speeding-up-process-time-while-archiving-files)

Comment: @Phrancis It says that at the end of the question..

Comment: Oh, okay thanks, didn't notice that

Comment: @Phrancis No problem my friend.

Comment: @Blorgbeard If you make that into an answer, I'll accept it, I did the fastest CompressionLevel and it went down to 28 seconds

Comment: All right, posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is pretty much just a wrapper for [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707.aspx), so there's not any "optimization" you can do, apart from passing different arguments to it.

You could try a different [`CompressionLevel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.compressionlevel.aspx) - for example:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startDir, zipDir, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
```

Although you should note that you will get worse compression (larger output files).

Comment: Incase you where curious the new average from adding this: `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startDir, zipDir, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);` is: 28.31527892 seconds